# postgresql связи с null

Tags: sql, postgresql

В общем есть таблица simple_table:

```
id, user_id, content
```

где user_id может быть пустым.
Стоит ли оставить как есть и сделать поле IS NULL + INDEX или лучше создать таблицу со связью:
users_simple_table:

```
id, user_id, simple_table_id
```

Насколько это адекватно и разумно?

Просто не очень понятно, если в таблице таких полей много, не проще ли их вынести, чтобы если поля пустые, глаза не мозолили

Comment: Всё зависит от "физики" процесса. А если тебе "пустые поля глаза мозолят" - то тебе явно заняться нечем, кроме как раскладыванием себе граблей "про запас".

Comment: @Akina дак вот и спрашиваю, чтобы не раскидывать грабли себе)))

Comment: Ну на текущий момент ответ простой - мало данных для осмысленного совета. Нужно нормальное описание предметной области, или как минимум описание того, что хранится в этой таблице, как соотносится с другими таблицами, и какие операции на ней ожидаются, с процентовкой по типам.

Comment: Null не вяжется

Comment: Имеет смысл выносить поле в отдельную таблицу только если количество заполненных хотя бы на порядок меньше общего числа строк.